# How to get a Provider from "@web3modal/react" using ether.js to get the connected signer and address to do a Transaction call?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web3modal

in Previous "Web3Modal" from "web3modal", can able to access, new Web3Modal().connect(). but in {Web3Modal} from "@web3modal/react", can't able to do. So, can't able to get a Provider.

I try to find a solution with implementation of a Manual button call for Connecting the wallet via web3modal and get a provider and signer provider using ethers.js and @web3modal/react

Answer (score 0):

To do this, i use not only web3modal/ethereum, but wagmi and viem:

```
import { EthereumClient, w3mConnectors, w3mProvider} from "@web3modal/ethereum";
import {configureChains, createConfig} from "@wagmi/core";
import {Web3Modal} from "@web3modal/html";
import {type HttpTransport} from 'viem'
```

in order to use a compatible provider and signer with web3modal, i will recommend you to implement this: [Wagmi/ethers adapter](https://wagmi.sh/core/ethers-adapters).

I hope this will help you.